# Have any studies been performed which show that campaigning for or being appointed to an office of public trust leads to criminal activity?

Tags: campaigning, crime, political-appointments

Consider

- [List of American state and local politicians convicted of crimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_state_and_local_politicians_convicted_of_crimes)
- [List of American federal politicians convicted of crimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_federal_politicians_convicted_of_crimes)

while in general persons who have been convicted of a crime are not necessarily prohibited from running for or being appointed to an office of public trust in the United States (see [Felons in Elected Office](https://www.factcheck.org/2008/11/felons-in-office/)), for the purposes of naivete we could presume that none of the persons convicted of crimes in the above lists had previously been convicted of a crime before campaigning for or being appointed to an office of public trust, and that they were not criminals who simply decided to campaign for public office or accept an appointment to a governmental agency head or become a judge simply to further their criminal enterprises, though if such naivete requires being unveiled and the conspiracy by specific individuals to profiteer from an office of public trust has factually been or be should exposed on the record, then so be it.

Have any studies been performed which show that campaigning for or being appointed an office of public trust (i.e., Congressperson; Senator; Judge; County Councilor; Mayor) *leads* to criminal activity; both in and of itself as to the practical nature of the work, bureaucracy and tendency of certain types of individuals to be engaged in those professions; and compared to criminal activity within professions which do not require public campaigns or being appointed to an office of public trust, e.g., a physical laborer; or is *initial* criminal behaviour equally proportional to professions which are won by campaigning or being politically appointed and professions which require only individual or team effort, but are not based on having access to public funds and upholding public trust?

Comment: It's a reasonable question but probably very hard to study. And whatever conclusion one might draw will likely be contested in terms of confounders etc. There are definitely personality factors involved in criminal propensity e.g. the [H from HEXACO](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1751-9004.2008.00134.x) but H also correlates with power‐seeking tendencies.

Comment: @Fizz Studying the lists themselves we could conclude that either campaigning or being politically appointed has a higher propensity for potential criminal activity than, for example, dentists, who began their professional career at the same time as first term in office; or, that some criminal enterprises specifically decide to expand their operation to politics and appointments to public offices. How could those conclusions be refuted based on only the facts presented at the linked lists?

Comment: I'm guessing you're aware of the flip-side of the coin, i.e. that environment plays a role too, via the [Stanford prison experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_prison_experiment) etc. I don't think one can draw any conclusions just from the Wikipedia lists. Dentists sometimes molest patients etc. Just because there's no Wikipedia list of criminal dentists doesn't mean they don't engage in crime; it just means most dentists are not notable according to Wikipedia's standard WP:N.

Comment: @Fizz Yes, we can draw conclusions from the list as a base from which to begin. We can state the facts that those individuals who _decided_ to become a professional politician or political apointee _decided_ to engage in criminal activity. What we cannot _easily_ determine is if those same individuals were criminals before they became a professional in the public having the responsibility of public trust; especially where they deny being a criminal, as any professional criminal might. We could get the list of the graduating class of the individuals and compare their criminal proclivity.

Comment: I meant you need additional data, which is not easily available.

Comment: @Fizz No, of course not "easy". Do not measure accuracy or precision by means of the effect being "easy" or not, rather, accurate or precise to the degree to settle the question. If not settle the question, present the adequate raw data for the future to more "easily", if that is their process of inquiry, posit additional facts to the answer. Even without additional data we have the facts of that _decision_ to engage in criminal activity _after_ knowledge of having the public trust; i.e., the criminal conduct here cannot be attributed to "mental illness" or "environment"; or can (has) it?

Comment: Two problems here.  First is simple opportunity: a lot of us might be willing to take bribes or misuse campaign funds, but unless we're in politics, we just don't have the chance.  Second, politics makes many neutral actions into crimes.  E.g. it might be quite the ordinary thing, and legal, for a wealthy man to pay off people with whom he's had sex.  Let him run for office, though, and it easily can be seen as criminal.  (And not just Trump: John Edwards & Dennis Hastert come to mind...)

Comment: The initial naivete of fledgling a politician seems hard to measure.  In the worst case a seemingly innocent politician who might have only appeared to have gone bad after election might have been a rotter from the cradle who only escaped conviction through social connections (family or criminal) and via the repeated abuse of a series of fall guys and scapegoats.

Comment: The wording of the question of confusing. The question that makes more sense to ask is whether people who campaign for or win public offices have a greater propensity to engage in criminal activity, or more opportunities to commit criminal activity, which is what the answer given explains. It isn't clear if these are the questions being asked or if a different question is being asked, due to the awkward wording.

Comment: @ohwilleke The question is clear.

Answer (score 5):

There aren't many direct studies on being in elected/appointed positions making you more likely to exhibit criminal behavior. There are more generalized studies that seem to imply that there is a possible link. People with more power are [better liars](http://www.engaged-zen.org/PDFarchive/PowerLying.pdf)/ more dishonest . There are also studies that seem to prove that [power leads to corruption.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1048984314000800) Leaders also tend to exhibit a lot of traits [similar to psychopaths.](https://www.forbes.com/sites/victorlipman/2013/04/25/the-disturbing-link-between-psychopathy-and-leadership/#73b20f284104) The sort of people attracted to these positions tend to be people that are more willing to break rules, and simply being in these positions makes those tendencies more prevalent. Criminal activity just requires these people to devolve past a certain point, which the positions seem to encourage.

Comment: You may want to bring some quotes from your links into the question. Links could die at any time, so link-only evidence will not always be available.

Comment: What's the source of the first paper? It looks like someone's term paper.

Comment: @indigochild: good question. It looks like they have an [extended version](http://www.leannetenbrinke.com/uploads/2/1/0/4/21049652/carney_et_al_under_review.pdf) but that also doesn't seem to have been formally published somewhere. The original short paper was "defended" on HBR: https://hbr.org/2010/05/defend-your-research-powerful-people-are-better-liars

Comment: From the 2nd paper "power interacted with endogenous testosterone in predicting corruption, which was highest when leader power and baseline testosterone were both high". I'll only vote for women now! (But then I remembered Brazil.) But also "Honesty predicted initial level of leader antisocial decisions; however, honesty did not shield leaders from the corruptive effect of power."

Comment: Looking at full text, honesty was measured on HEXACO in that one; see my comment under the question for a similar study (in that respect).